# Flutter Error: Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

I updated Flutter to the latest version. I get an error like this:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on SM A528B in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

/Users/ebuzersariyerlioglu/Desktop/lgs_ingilizce_panda/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new app.rive.rive.RivePlugin());
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class RivePlugin
  location: package app.rive.rive
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

what should I do?

This is flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I'm also wondering if anyone else is getting this error other than me. Because I couldn't see it on other blogs.

Comment: have you sync gradle after update ?

Comment: how does one sync the gradle?
`flutter clean` 
`flutter build`  
?

Comment: Does this answer your question, [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032396/applying-flutters-app-plugin-loader-gradle-plugin-imperatively-using-the-apply-s/78091514#78091514).

Answer (score 1):

Delete `android/settings.gradle` , after delete run `flutter create .`, to create new `setting.gradle` , after that should update "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" to last version of kotlin

for more information:[enter link description here](https://https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)