# Applying Flutters app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method which is deprecated, will be removed in a future release

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, deprecated

After Upgrading the Flutter version to `3.19.0` I am getting this warning when running the app:

> You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin
> imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle
> plugins with the declarative plugins block:
> https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
>
> You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the
> apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a
> future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the
> declarative plugins block:
> https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

How to remove these deprecated gradle settings.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First easy way to update it is to delete the android directory of your flutter project and run the following command in your flutter repository

```
flutter create .
```

> But before that please note that it will create all the android directory from scratch and you will loose settings like if you have added permissions, launcher icons or have done some work in native side etc so be on safer side initialize git repo and commit the code before deleting it and compare android directory after running the following command

> if you have created the git repository then restore all the previous files except both project and app level
> `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`

another way is to follow the steps given in the official documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) which was little bit confusing for me for the first time. be careful while following the guide otherwise you might get into trouble.

Answer (score 16):

Upgrade your flutter to latest version
then delete android folder in your project
then type `flutter create .` in terminal or cmd if you're using windows
and done

Comment: This is the easiest and the cleanest solution. Bear in mind though, you need to copy certain files like build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml, and resource files before delete existing android folder. Moreover if have changed the name of the project folder like I did, you may want to change it back temporarily before run `flutter create .`.

Comment: Good luck configuring many things from scratch. Worst solution except if the project was recently started.

Answer (score 13):

I have solved the problem by following instructions from Flutter Docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Here is what i have done:

Firstly, I have completely replaced `android/settings.gradle` file like this:

```
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "{agpVersion}" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

Then, inside `android/settings.gradle` file more specifically inside `plugins{}` I have changed `{agpVersion}` with `7.2.0` and `{kotlinVersion}` with `1.7.20`

Then, i have removed the whole `buildscript{}` from `android/build.gradle` file. Now the `android/build.gradle` looks like this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then inside `android/app/build.gradle` file i have deleted some lines. Those lines are,

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

and,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Then also in this file i have added some lines in the top. The lines are,

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

And lastly, inside `dependencies{}` of `android/app/build.gradle` i also replaced `$kotlin_version` with `1.7.20`

So, Now the `android/app/build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
    (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.brachealthcare.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` 
works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20"
}
```

So, I just edited 3 files [`android/settings.gradle`], [`android/build.gradle`] and [`android/app/build.gradle`] and the issue is resolved. Hope this helps. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 9):

It is necessary to migrate the project if it was created on an older version. Here are the instructions: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.

Comment: For me that documentation is useless. If applied I get some errors, the app does not start anymore and no clue how to fix it.

Comment: This documentation is useful; I recommend you use it. Also create a new example project, then check the gradle configurations in the new example project. Together with the documentation, the error will be gone

Comment: I used that documentation to update a flutter app, more or less as expected but lots of incorrect path.
Now building the native app, that uses a flutter module I get the warning again and this documentation is useless and leads to loads of errors, starting with undefined flutter.sdk !

Comment: After following it I get this error:

[!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app
<app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

Answer (score 4):

Since Flutter 3.16, projects generated with flutter create use the Plugin DSL to apply Gradle plugins. Projects created with versions of Flutter prior to 3.16 need to be migrated manually.

To Follow The steps:

Step one :
Replace the contents of /android/settings.gradle with the below

Moving (Plugins) Section to new Below one  Out of pluginManagement curly Brackets

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false // Newer Version
}
```

Add this Section to pluginManagement  Below Line >>

```
includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

Step Two:
Remove the whole buildscript block from <app-src/android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Step Three:
Remove this code if it's found from <app-src/android/build.gradle:

```
-def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
-if (flutterRoot == null) {
-    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
-}

-apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
-apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
-apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Last Step : in the same file at first line add this code :

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

Finally You can follow instructions From Flutter Docs:
[Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)

Comment: In my android/app/build.gradle i made those changes but i also had dependency {} block at the bottom of the file with the line: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` and i changed it to `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.22"`. So i wanted to ask is there any way to not specify version using just variable containing kotlin version?

Comment: actually  idon't know for now but in latest version of flutter this line should be empty. because they moved it to settings.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried to follow [these](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.) instructions, did not really help, leaded to other compile problems, because my gradle file had other customizations too.

The problem was in one of the three files

- app/build.gradle
- build.gradle
- settings.gradle

After trying to fix them based on hints found on the web I tried to delete them completely and let them be created by flutter itself using the command `flutter create . --project-name aRandomName`. This creates many files, you can delete all except the three mentioned above. Using the git changes comparison you can fix them adding what is missing taking notes from the official documentation linked above, [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.) again.

Answer (score 0):

**WHY**

After Flutter 3.16, they introduced a new way to apply Gradle plugins called *Plugin DSL*, before they used something called *imperative apply script*. So everyone who created Flutter project before 3.16 need to use this new method.

**HOW**

First in your project level settings.gradle `android/settings.gradle` **remove** whole code and **paste** this

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '7.3.0' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version '1.7.10' apply false

}

include ":app"
```

In project level build.gradle `android/build.gradle`, **Remove** the whole `buildscript` block.

This how `android/build.gradle` looks like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And in app level build.gradle `android/app/build.gradle` **remove** these 2 block of code

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

and also **remove** single line code in `dependencies` block

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

You may have get an error telling to change your gradle version in `app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

If you get that error change that too.

For more information, check out this [official link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply).

Comment: I now get an error:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_cu2n1bhns4wx5avqvxwcpata4$_run_closure2@72306ef] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

What do I do here?

Comment: @kilokahn try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37252114/18186375

Comment: Where's the information about adding plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue week ago after updating flutter version , tried the methods above but leads me to infinite loop of problems, I restored everything like it was before

> by that I mean the `setting.gradle` and `build.gradle` in android
> and the one in app

Then I've updated my `setting.gradle` to this one and fixed the problem without editing anything else !

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project with an old version of Flutter, you need to migrate.
To do this, first do all the steps step by step. (Of course, you can completely delete the Android project file and run `Flutter create .` command)
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
If your problem is not resolved, use `flutter doctor` instructions and follow all its steps.
If your problem is still not solved, the problem is with the Kotlin version you are using, which is in the `android/setting.gradle` file (and the best used version is displayed in the VS Code error in debug console.) Replace it with the current version.

> Don't forget to use `Flutter Run` after completing the steps!