# Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: flutter

You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

try to follow your guide

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

but it didn't work so I did the following

I faced the same error, I know very little about programming, I try to do the best I can so the error is very recent, I tried to look for solutions and no one gave answers, nothing helped, so I came up with an idea to use ChatGpt on this problem and it worked I recommend that you first send the error that appears in the Android console, then he would tell you the solution, comment that you do not know how to program and in the same line send your build.gradle file and ask him to do it for you, modify the file and that's it. They try it again and it works perfectly. I hope it helps you. Sorry, I don't speak English but I wanted to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question, [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032396/applying-flutters-app-plugin-loader-gradle-plugin-imperatively-using-the-apply-s/78091514#78091514).