# How have others resolved issues with Flutter and the Gradle Plugin?

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin

You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

[image]

I want to run my flutter project

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying Flutters app\_plugin\_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method which is deprecated, will be removed in a future release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032396/applying-flutters-app-plugin-loader-gradle-plugin-imperatively-using-the-apply-s)