# VS Code: problems with text appearing in emulator for flutter app

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, emulation

I'm a trainee in a really small company, so I don't have much experience and currently I'm having trouble with the android emulator during a test with VS Code in which text doesn't appear, also I didn't create the project, they just gave me access to it and they created it using flutterflow, so I don't know if that matters.

Problem:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

The expected image was taken from bluestacks and that works well, also I launch it in my own phone and it also works there.

I imagine it has something to do with the Android build.gradle since this appears in the debug console during test:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
```

I already tried the link the output gives (https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) but that completely destroys the project, and it stops working altogether and honestly I'm completely lost.

Comment: Can you tell us which flutter version you are using? Run this command in terminal "flutter --version". Also I found this answer on your question, you should try it out -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78078686/12403892

Comment: Flutter 3.19.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git, also i tried the fix in the question you posted and it also broke the app, it seems the way some plugins are called are changed when i tried the fix in the question.

Comment: Downgrade your flutter version to 3.15 or less using this command "flutter downgrade <version> (example: flutter downgrade v1.2.1)". I think that it should work now because as the documentation says : "In Flutter 3.16, support was added for applying these plugins with Gradle’s declarative plugins {} block (also called the Plugin DSL) and it is now the recommended approach. Since Flutter 3.16, projects generated with flutter create use the Plugin DSL to apply Gradle plugins. Projects created with versions of Flutter prior to 3.16 need to be migrated manually."

Comment: If you want to use latest flutter version you should follow the migration instructions provided in error message. https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply