Flutter application not running after upgrading to 3.24.1 due to Gradle issue
I recently upgraded my Flutter application to version 3.24.1, and since then, I’ve been unable to run the app. I’m encountering the following Gradle issue:
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.1/lib/src/guid.dart:32:9: Error: Type 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found.
  final UnmodifiableUint8ListView bytes;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.1/lib/src/guid.dart:32:9: Error: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't a type.
  final UnmodifiableUint8ListView bytes;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.1/lib/src/guid.dart:52:17: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.    
    return Guid(UnmodifiableUint8ListView(guid));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.1/lib/src/guid.dart:56:31: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.    
  factory Guid.zero() => Guid(UnmodifiableUint8ListView(Uint8List(16)));
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.1/lib/src/guid.dart:100:17: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.   
    return Guid(UnmodifiableUint8ListView(Uint8List.fromList(guidAsBytes)));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.4.10/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:5:7: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'.
      UnmodifiableUint8ListView(Uint8List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.4.10/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:7:7: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint32ListView'.
      UnmodifiableUint32ListView(Uint32List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/archive-3.4.10/lib/src/bzip2/bzip2.dart:9:7: Error: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableInt32ListView'.
      UnmodifiableInt32ListView(Int32List(0));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\code\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1687

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\code\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             82.2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I’ve tried cleaning the project and re-syncing Gradle, but the problem persists. I've also checked my build.gradle files for any outdated dependencies but haven't found anything unusual.
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780], locale en-AE)
    • Flutter version 3.24.1 on channel stable at C:\code\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5874a72aa4 (8 days ago), 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
    • Engine revision c9b9d5780d
    • Dart version 3.5.1
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\jamal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\jamal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.2)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33502.453
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\jamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM G715FN (mobile) • R58RB0ZASKF • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • Windows (desktop)  • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780]
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.120
    • Edge (web)         • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 128.0.2739.42

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Has anyone else encountered this issue after upgrading? What steps should I take to resolve this and successfully run my app?

Check This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032396/applying-flutters-app-plugin-loader-gradle-plugin-imperatively-using-the-apply-s

It is a known issue: https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_cli/issues/263
You need to update win32 dart package.
Go to your project and update the minimum Dart SDK version.
For me, it is 3.5.0
pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.5.0 <4.0.0"

Then clean pub cache:
flutter pub cache clean

And update outdated dart packages:
flutter pub outdated 
flutter pub upgrade

In the logs you should see:
> win32 5.5.4 (was 5.2.0)


This worked for me.
dependency_overrides:
   win32: ^5.5.4


I deleted my pubspec.lock file then use command
flutter clean and flutter pub get
this resolve my problem and project runs without any error

I fixed this issue by updating win32 flutter upgrade win32 package
first I tried by changing the flutter version but not fixed,
After reading https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_cli/issues/263 this blog
some issue comes from syncfusion package also the new flutter version having problem with sycfusion try remove the package (in some cases the issue will fix)
found everyone saying syncfusion issues

Also upgrading dart version   sdk: ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0"
in pubspec.yaml worked for me

Here is the solution for this problem, just run this and thank me later
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

