# Cant run app after upgrading flutter to 3.19.0 - Project with path app could not be found in project camera_android

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I recently upgrade to flutter 3.19.0 and did the migration guide for the "Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins" but now i am getting the following error while trying to run my application on android:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\myuser\Projects\exampleapp\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':camera_android'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried using different combinations of minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion, currently (24 and 33). Running with verbose options does not give more info:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':camera_android'.
```

but nothing seems to work, any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try first to upgrade gradually, like the [flutter release changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes) says.
If you dont know, try to upgrade to 3.16.0 if not working yet try the other above.

I did that on my project, first upgraded to 3.16.0 then to 3.19.0 with some help from stackoverflow. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78015908/5331509)

> delete android/settings.gradle , after delete run <flutter create .>, to create new setting.gradle , after that should update "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" to last version of kotlin
>
> for more information:[enter link description here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-319)

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue but with android_alarm_manager_plus. It turns out, I forgot to add the `include ':app'` in `settings.gradle`.